# Unexpected token :

Tags: javascript

```
 <script>
    function createPerson(firstName, lastName)
    {
        return
        {
            firstName: firstName,
            lastName: lastName, //This line!!!
            getFullName: function() {
                return this.firstName + " " + this.lastName;
            },
            greet: function(person) 
            {
             alert("Hello, " + person.getFullName() + "I'm " + this.getFullName());
            }

        };
    }
    var johnDoe = createPerson("John" , "Doe");
    var janeDoe = createPerson("Jane" , "Doe");

    johnDoe.greet(janeDoe);
</script>
```

Why does this line throw an error ? "Unexpected token :". This is an example from a book, I did exactly the same thing but this error is showing up. Don't know what's wrong.

Comment: `return` and `{` must be on the same line.

Comment: You may find a website such as http://jshint.com/ helpful for pointing out syntax errors in the future.

Comment: *"Why does this line throw an error ?"* `{..}` is interpreted as a **block**, `firstName:` is interpreted as a **label**, `firstName, lastName: lastName` is interpreted as the **comma operator** which expects two **expressions**, `lastName: lastName` is not a valid expression because `:` is not valid here. Hence the error *"Unexpected token :"*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have

```
return
{
```

Javascript has Automatic Semicolon Insertion; to the interpter, your code looks like

```
return;
{
```

because the `{` is on the *next* line, and because it's legal to exist on its own.

Put the `{` on the same line as the `return` instead:

```
return {
  // ...
```

Answer (score 5):

You can't break a line in front of a `return` statement.

```js
function createPerson(firstName, lastName)
{
    return {
        firstName: firstName,
        lastName: lastName, //This line!!!
        getFullName: function() {
            return this.firstName + " " + this.lastName;
        },
        greet: function(person) 
        {
         console.log("Hello, " + person.getFullName() + "I'm " + this.getFullName());
        }

    };
}
var johnDoe = createPerson("John" , "Doe");
var janeDoe = createPerson("Jane" , "Doe");

johnDoe.greet(janeDoe);
```

Answer (score 3):

Remove the newline after the `return`. As a newline is treated as an `;` due to JavaScript's *automatic semicolon insertion*

**Demo**

```js
function foo() {
  return
  'foo';
}
console.log(foo()) // undefined

function bar() {
  return 'bar';
}
console.log(bar()) // bar
```

**Your snippet fixed**

```js
function createPerson(firstName, lastName)
{
    return {
        firstName: firstName,
        lastName: lastName,
        getFullName: function() {
            return this.firstName + " " + this.lastName;
        },
        greet: function(person) 
        {
         console.log("Hello, " + person.getFullName() + "I'm " + this.getFullName());
        }

    };
}
var johnDoe = createPerson("John" , "Doe");
var janeDoe = createPerson("Jane" , "Doe");

johnDoe.greet(janeDoe);
```

---

**To elaborate on the actual error:**

> `{..}` is interpreted as a block. `firstName:` is interpreted as a
>   label. `firstName, lastName: lastName` is interpreted as the comma
>   operator which expects *two* expressions, `lastName: lastName` is not a
>   valid expression because `:` is not valid here. Hence the error
>   **"Unexpected token :"**. – *Felix Kling*

Answer (score 2):

It fails because it's equivalent to:

```
function createPerson(firstName, lastName)
{
    return;
    {
        firstName: firstName,
        lastName: lastName, //This line!!!
        getFullName: function() {
            return this.firstName + " " + this.lastName;
        },
        greet: function(person) 
        {
         alert("Hello, " + person.getFullName() + "I'm " + this.getFullName());
        }

    };
}
var johnDoe = createPerson("John" , "Doe");
var janeDoe = createPerson("Jane" , "Doe");

johnDoe.greet(janeDoe);
```

due to automatic semi-colon insertion. Which is why the more common style is opening bracken on the same line.

```
function createPerson(firstName, lastName) {
    return {
        firstName: firstName,
        lastName: lastName, //This line!!!
        getFullName: function() {
            return this.firstName + " " + this.lastName;
        },
        greet: function(person) {
         alert("Hello, " + person.getFullName() + "I'm " + this.getFullName());
        }

    };
}
var johnDoe = createPerson("John" , "Doe");
var janeDoe = createPerson("Jane" , "Doe");

johnDoe.greet(janeDoe);
```